# Windows XP mode is started only when user is logged in Windows 7

Tags: windows-xp-mode

Is it possible to set Windows XP mode so it can be started (after PC has been rebooted) automatically without actual logging in Windows 7?

Answer (score -1):

It isn't recommended but it is [possible](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows-7/99d4fe75-3f22-499b-85fc-c7a2c4f728af) to auto-login Win7:

1. Press (windows key) + R.
2. Type "control userpasswords2" and press Enter.

   Security note: If UAC is enabled, then you’ll get a UAC prompt on screen. Please specify
   credentials or permission to pass the UAC elevation.
3. Select your account from the list.
4. Uncheck the "Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer. "
5. Click Apply and a dialog will appear

Once you've configured Win7 to login automatically, put a shortcut to WinXP in your All Users' 'startup' folder.

Comment: Thanks.Is RDP still awailable after this set up?

Comment: Yes. Everything that XP can natively do, so long as you don't have it turned off or blocked by a firewall

Comment: Well, I ment RDP in Windows 7. Will it be still awailable? Becaouse I think that you need user name and password to log in using RDP.

Comment: Don't know. You could try and let us know.